# Consuming ArcGIS MapServer as FeatureServer in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, map-service, feature-service

I work on ArcGIS 10.3, and I try to find a way to convert MapServer into FeatureServer.

The MapServer has no attribute table, and there no way to change the symbology.
The FeatureServer has attribute table and after I add it to the map, i can export it into feature layer and it acts as a regular layer.

I found the layer here:

https://gwa.israntique.org.il/mobidic/rest/services

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You've tagged this as `mapserver` ~ https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/mapserver/info is that what you mean?

Comment: Only the map service publisher (or the site administrator) can alter a published service. Please edit the question to specify that you have only consumer rights on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can unless you are the original publisher or administrator of the service.

When creating a new service or editing an already published service, there is an option to "allow feature access". That creates a feature service.

Comment: You can also alter the service *after* publishing.